# Extract keys and values from hstore string in R

Tags: r, regex, hstore

I'm working in `R` with strings obtained from [OpenStreetMap](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html#other-tags-field) and stored using the [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/hstore.html) data type. For example:

```
"comment"=>"Removed junction=roundabout as some entrances have right of way. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:junction%3Droundabout","lit"=>"yes","maxspeed"=>"30 mph","oneway"=>"yes","surface"=>"asphalt"
```

I would like to create a `regex` (or any other approach is fine) to extract all keys and all values. Please notice that keys and values could contain the characters `=`, `>`, `\"`, or `,`. The ideal approach should use only functions implemented in base-R packages.

**EDIT - Expected output**

If the input is

```
"comment"=>"Removed junction=roundabout as some entrances have right of way. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:junction%3Droundabout","lit"=>"yes","maxspeed"=>"30 mph","oneway"=>"yes","surface"=>"asphalt"
```

then the expected output should be something like

```
keys: "comment", "lit", "maxspeed", "oneway", "surface"
values: "Removed junction=roundabout as some entrances have right of way. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:junction%3Droundabout", "yes", "30 mph", "yes", "asphalt"
```

If the input is

```
"lit"=>"no","foot"=>"designated","horse"=>"designated","bicycle"=>"yes","surface"=>"gravel","old_name"=>"Freshwater, Yarmouth & Newport Railway","prow_ref"=>"F61"
```

then the output should be like

```
keys: "lit", "foot", "horse", "bicycle", "surface", "old_name"
values: "no", "designated", "designated", "yes", "gravel", "Freshwater, Yarmouth & Newport"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use tidyverse approaches

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(str1) %>% 
   separate_rows(str1, sep = '"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,') %>%
   separate(str1, into = c('key', 'value'), sep= '"=>"') %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), str_remove_all, pattern = '"'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
#   key      value                                                                                                                            
#   <chr>    <chr>                                                                                                                            
# 1 comment  Removed junction=roundabout as some entrances have right of way. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:junction%3Droundabout
# 2 lit      yes                                                                                                                              
# 3 maxspeed 30 mph                                                                                                                           
# 4 oneway   yes                                                                                                                              
# 5 surface  asphalt                                                                                                                          
# 6 lit      no                                                                                                                               
# 7 foot     designated                                                                                                                       
# 8 horse    designated                                                                                                                       
# 9 bicycle  yes                                                                                                                              
#10 surface  gravel                                                                                                                           
#11 old_name Freshwater, Yarmouth & Newport Railway                                                                                           
#12 prow_ref F61
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("\"comment\"=>\"Removed junction=roundabout as some entrances have right of way. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:junction%3Droundabout\",\"lit\"=>\"yes\",\"maxspeed\"=>\"30 mph\",\"oneway\"=>\"yes\",\"surface\"=>\"asphalt\"", 
"\"lit\"=>\"no\",\"foot\"=>\"designated\",\"horse\"=>\"designated\",\"bicycle\"=>\"yes\",\"surface\"=>\"gravel\",\"old_name\"=>\"Freshwater, Yarmouth & Newport Railway\",\"prow_ref\"=>\"F61\""
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  read.table(text=gsub(',?([^,]+)=>',"\n\\1:", string, perl = TRUE), sep=":", 
             col.names = c("Key", "value"))
       Key                                  value
1      lit                                     no
2     foot                             designated
3    horse                             designated
4  bicycle                                    yes
5  surface                                 gravel
6 old_name Freshwater, Yarmouth & Newport Railway
7 prow_ref                                    F61
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know if it's possible to modify the regex and take into account that `\"` may be included in the string? For example: `"maxwidth"=>"6'6\"","sidewalk"=>"none"`. If I run your code with that string it fails (I think because of  `\"`)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to share the "offending" string, but if you can't copy the previous example, maybe the following string works: `string <- "\"maxwidth\"=>\"6'6\\\"\",\"sidewalk\"=>\"none\""; cat(string)`

Comment: @agila store the results above as `df` for example and do `print.data.frame(df, quote = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks! If you can help me one more time, I summarised the error here: https://gist.github.com/agila5/573b26b89fe17dc9b7d7eef0771fa19c

Comment: @agila. The problem here is that there is an incomplete `"` in your string. You should consider cleaning the data first to make it a valid string.